# Pass self of class A object within class B

Tags: python, class, oop

Say, I have to classes `A` and `B`, and a member function of `B` requires `self` as an input argument.

Something like this (doesn't work):

```
import A

class B:
    def func(self):
        A_obj = A.A()
        required_for_calc = A.func_A(A_obj.__self__)
```

Where `A` looks like:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 1

    def func_A(self):
        # do something with self here...
```

Comment: `A_obj`'s `self` is just `A_obj`.

Comment: What is `A_obj = A.A()`? Isn't this code mixing classes and modules?

Answer (score 1):

`self` is the object itself:

```
required_for_calc = A.func_A(A_obj)
```

or simply:

```
required_for_calc = A_obj.func_A()
```

Answer (score -1):

`A` "self" will never be accesible if you do not instantiate the `A` class, this is because `__init__` method is only called on instantiation. what you can do is subclass `A` and as long as you don't shadow `__init__`, that is defining another `__init__` in `b` without using `super()`, you will have `self` available.

```
import A

class B(A):
# the rest of the code
```

In this situation `func_A` is already part of class B because is inherited.